# centos | perl processes are not shown

Tags: linux, ps

I have a centos server in which I have install perl package to run some perl scripts. today I run some perl scripts, and when I run `ps -ef  | grep perl` it shows nothing although the scripts are working properly.

When I use `pkill -f (name_of_script)` the perl process stopped however they are not shown at all.

Note that yesterday I deleted a user ( X ) which was affected to folder /home/scripts. What do you think the problem is from?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for not showing the process in `ps -ef` might be due to the process being run as a background process. In that case, the process won't be associated with the terminal where you started it from and thus won't be shown in the output of `ps -ef`. To see all processes running on the system, including background processes, you can use `ps aux` instead.